# Using Script Instead Of Proper Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script on spreadsheet Capitalizing first column.
It is a great tool. But now, i would like to apply the Proper to all the data of the sheet, and not only the first column. Could someone tell me how to do that?
Regards

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('Capitalize', 'proper')
        .addToUi();
}


function proper() {
    var arr = [],
        s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    s.getRange('A2:A')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function(r) {
            if (r[0]) arr.push([toTitleCase(r[0])])
        });
    s.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
        .setValues(arr);
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0)
            .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
            .toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you can't *run* the snippet, it shouldn't be a snippet, just a code block. (And don't post JavaScript code in the HTML panel of the snippet editor.)

Comment: Just guessing here, but surely you'd change `s.getRange('A2:A')` to something getting all the cells? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry about that T.J. i am not coder at all. I am just learning. I would like to select all cells containing data. Or, select columns A to T. Regards

Comment: It does not work by changing getRange values.

Comment: There is already a built in function called Proper(), so you could use that in a second sheet. Wrap it in an arrayformula and it is one formula in cell A2 on Sheet2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2:A),, PROPER(Sheet1!A2:T)))`  I may be able to look the code over later.

Comment: Thank you so much. But i would like something script based. Withing adding any sheet. The work document ever have more than 20 sheets, and they do not want any extra sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Proper function to

```
function proper() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
s.getDataRange()
    .setValues(
        s.getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map(function (r) {
            return r.map(function (el) {
               return !el ? null : typeof el !== 'string' && el ? el : toTitleCase(el);
            })
        })
    )
}
```

and see if that works ?

Note that this code will not throw an error if you have numeric values in the sheet.